# Excel VBA - MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 Log on and change to 2nd URL

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to log on a scrape our member directory with MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 (4,000 entries).  Back when IE was still an option,  I simply logged on with IE, got authorization, and did the XML download.  Without IE, I have tried the same process with selenium.  Its NO-GO.  I know almost nothing about XMLHTTP60 and APIs, but I am trying to learn. I have had a similar situation on the USGA GHIN site that I resolved with help as follows

```
    Const URL = "https://api2.ghin.com/api/v1/public/login.json?"
    Const Link = "https://api2.ghin.com/api/v1/followed_golfers/"
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, ghinNum$, lastName$
    Dim AdminGHINnumber As String, AdminLASTNAME As String
    
    
 On Error GoTo 1000
    AdminGHINnumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I5").Value
    AdminLASTNAME = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("I3").Value
    
    ghinNum = AdminGHINnumber           'put your ghinNum here
    lastName = AdminLASTNAME
    
    'ghinNum = "XXXXXXXX"            'put your ghinNum here
    'lastName = "YYYYYY"

    With http
        .Open "GET", URL & "ghinNumber=" & ghinNum & "&lastName=" & lastName & "&remember_me=false", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://www.ghin.com/login"
        .Send
        .Open "GET", Link & ghinNum & ".json", False
        .Send
    End With

    'MsgBox Http.responseText
    Debug.Print http.responseText
    Sheets("GHIN_Input").Range("A2").Value = http.responseText
```

Can someone suggest a similar scheme to get me loged on to to the new site with the Code below?"

````
**TROUBLE CODE I am TRYING TO SOLVE BELOW **
**LOG On URL:  https://www.pgawest.com/club/scripts/login/login.asp
Next URL: https://www.pgawest.com/member-home/profiles?LET=A**
```''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
**TROUBLE CODE I am TRYING TO SOLVE BELOW ** 
```''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub PGAWest_XML2()
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGw6r5GVA5g&t=519s
Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim NextHRef As String
Dim NextURL As String


If MsgBox("First IE and Log in on the Site.  Then Leave the broweser open on the desktop. -- Is that done?" & Chr(iChar) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Next Letter ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, " ") = vbYes Then
        GoTo 100
    Else
        Exit Sub
End If

XMLReq.Open "GET", PGAWestMemURL & Chr(65), False
XMLReq.send

If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If ' 7:05

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
Set XMLReq = Nothing

100
Call Delete_WS


ActiveSheet.Name = "A"

'******************************* LETTER CHANGER ON MENU BAR - Set New Worksheet ****************************************
For iChar = 65 To 90
Stop
PGAWestMemURL = "https://www.pgawest.com/member-home/profiles?LET=A"
    XMLReq.Open "GET", PGAWestMemURL '& Chr(iChar), False 'https://www.pgawest.com/member-home/profiles?LET=A
    XMLReq.send
 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub
End If '
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
````

'''etc - all of the rest of the code has worked fine in the past

No data comes back in the request

Comment: Does the code ever reach the `Stop` statement within the `For iChar = 65 To 90` loop? If it does, the Stop statement will be highlighted in yellow and you should press F5 or go to Run > Continue to keep on executing the code. However, until you have the code working properly, I would change the loop to `For iChar = 65 To 65` so it only runs once

Comment: No, that part of the code  works just fine. 

In fact, I’m able to use a browser and download the entire database. It’s the XML piece that I’m having a problem with. It appears to me that they are blocking an XML response or I don’t understand the header I need or an API call.

Comment: the Char(65) is the starting point for an alphabet loop lower in the code not shown here.  I loop A -to Z in the directory, or Char(65) to Char (90).  In any case, that work just fine.  Its simply that I get nothing back from my XMLReq. Open.  I use all of the same code with Selenium Web browser and it works perfectly

Comment: Due to how that site is organised, the `If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then` test won't be enough to tell you whether you are logged in successfully. That's because if you aren't logged in, there will be two 301 redirects and then a 200 status with the logon page. The XMLHTTP60 object doesn't return anything for the 301 redirects and thus it will return a 200 status even if you're not logged in

Comment: I would suggest that after you've set the body of HTMLDoc to the response text, add a test to look for the login form, something like `If Not HTMLDoc.getElementById("memberLogin") Is Nothing Then` and within that If block, put up a MsgBox with an appropriate error then exit the sub

Comment: Thanks everyone I am traveling right now but I will be back next week and give those suggestions to try

Comment: thnk you  - I will try that